# WebBrowser multiple instance in Azure cloud

Tags: authentication, azure, browser, multiple-instances, scrape

We are having requirement for multiple instance of the WebBrowser components, running simultaneously in the Windows Azure worker role instance.

What is the best approach on implementing this? Our findings so far, made us believe that every new WebBrowser instance kills previous one and then stuck itself.

Could you also recommend best way of logining in on the web page, but without use of "HttpWebRequets", "WebRequest" or "WebClient"? We believed "WebBrowser" is our magic trick, but it seems it isn't so handy, especially on Azure cloud.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, the WebBrowser control is a Windows Forms control. Is your app Windows Forms based? If so, this is not a good choice for exposing a UI, as your web visitors have no way of viewing the user interface.

As far as what will and won't run in Windows Azure worker roles: Worker roles are essentially Windows 2008 Server R2 or SP2, so whatever you run locally *should* run in Windows Azure, aside from sharing desktop UI's. The results of running multiple WebBrowser controls in Windows Azure shouldn't be any different than running on a local server.

Comment: Tnks David. Yes, WebBrowser is from System.Windows.Forms... 
Our app isn't Windows Forms based. It is kind of screen scrape/crawler service, collecting pages which are located behind login forms. 
WebBrowser control was obvious choice for the login task, but once deployed to the cloud, it behaves odd. Could you recommend alternatives for this login tasks?

Comment: In the past, there were some issues with WebBrowser in Window Azure due to GDI issues. I’m not sure if those problems have been resolved. If the WebBrowser control has been updated to use IE 9 or later, it will work fine, as IE 9 started to use DirectX rather than the deprecated GDI. As for running multiple instances of WebBrowser, I don’t think there will be any issues.